# Overriding Function As Task and Touching UI Elements

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await, task

I have a function in a UI element that is overriding a function in the base class. This function has a return type of Task(Of ReturnData) and touches UI elements but does not have anything to await. What is the proper way for me to write the below (obviously simplified) function?

```
Private Overrides Function UpdateData As Task(Of ReturnData)
    textBox1.text = "new text"
    return new ReturnData("data")
End Function
```

I cannot surround the whole function in a Task.Run() as that would cause the UI element to not be running in the correct thread. I can do the below, but it feels hacky:

```
Private Overrides Async Function UpdateData As Task(Of ReturnData)
    textBox1.text = "new text"
    await Task.CompletedTask
    return new ReturnData("data")
End Function
```

Comment: Just a note, the UI should be modified in the UI thread or through the respective controls dispatcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Task.FromResult` for a synchronous method implementation that returns a `Task(Of T)`.

```
Private Overrides Function UpdateData As Task(Of ReturnData)
    textBox1.text = "new text"
    return Task.FromResult(new ReturnData("data"))
End Function
```

Use `Task.CompletedTask` for a synchronous method implementation that returns a `Task`.

```
Private Overrides Function UpdateData As Task
    textBox1.text = "new text"
    return Task.CompletedTask
End Function
```